# Open the Options Menu by clicking on the button

Tags: android

How Options Menu can be opened by clicking a button?
The following code does not work:

```
openOptionsMenu();
```

Thanks

Comment: What class is your `Activity` extending?

Comment: Can you please provide us with a sample of your code?

Comment: You mean overflow options menu??

Comment: Yes, my code to add items: ((((((((((( @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add("َAbout");
        menu.add("Exit");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); )))))))

Comment: please take a look at our [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and try to update your question, as it is currently written, it will be difficult for others to help you out.

Comment: I answered my previous question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved. I use the `Options Menu` instead of **`Popup Menu`**.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to simulate a KeyEvent. This makes the options menu appears

```
    BaseInputConnection  mInputConnection = new BaseInputConnection( findViewById(R.id.main_content), true);
KeyEvent kd = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
KeyEvent ku = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(kd);
mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(ku);
```